# Getting error in form_validation > set_rules > valid_email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter framework, my code is:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|numeric|exact_length[10]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address' , 'trim');
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
    $this->update_info();
}
```

Above code generate following error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error
Message: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::substr()
Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\libraries\Form_validation.php
Line Number: 1241
```

For just checking I've tried two things and error removed, but these are not the right way, so I need correct solution.

1. When I've removed `valid_email` from `set_rules` then code is working.
2. Code is working after commenting `Line Number: 1241` in the file (where I've got error) `system\libraries\Form_validation.php`

i.e.

```
1241: $str = self::substr($str, 0, ++$atpos).idn_to_ascii(self::substr($str, $atpos), 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
```

Codeigniter Version: 3.1.11
PHP Version: 7.4.2

Comment: I suppose that's because you use trim and numeric at the same time

Comment: @Vickel: No, I've checked it by removing all `trim` from `set_rules`, still the same error. I think its about `valid_email`

Answer (score 0):

Add email helper

```
$this->load->helper('email');
```

For email validation set this way

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
```

For mobile number validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number ', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]'); //{10} for 10 digits number
```

Comment: Nops ! not working. Still the same error exists. :(

Comment: Hide this line $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|numeric|exact_length[10]'); check my updated answer and try again